# Low-lying excited states in nuclei

Tags: nuclear-physics

How are the parity and spin of excited states of nuclei measured experimentally. I imagine that the energy can be easily measured by exciting the nucleus (by colliding it with a nucleon or electron for example) and then measuring the emitted photons. But how can one infer the spin and parity associated with that decay? Thank you!